# Is there a difference between the Earth's magnetic field and an applied magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, geomagnetism

I want to use the HMC2003 3-Axis Analog Magnetometer and the manual says that it only works on applied magnetic fields like a permanent magnet so is there a difference between that and the earth's in terms of strength and other factors? If there isn't much of a difference would it ultimately measure the earth's magnetic field?

Comment: Aside from factors of a thousand or more in field strength… Earth’s field is in the 10’s of microTesla - what are the specs on your sensor?

Comment: Data sheet that I looked at didn't say "applied magnetic field" anywhere, but what makes you think that if you bring the sensor near the Earth, that you aren't "applying" the Earth's field?

Comment: The device is designed to measure small differences in small magnetic fields of about the same strength as the earth's field (about 50 micro Tesla or 0.5 gauss). That's probably what it is for. It isn't designed to handle the strong fields nearby permanent magnets.